# Extend generic interface with strongly typed implementations

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a Transformer interface:

```
interface Transformer<K> {
    type: string,
    apply<K>(data: K) : K
}
```

I want to create 2 interface that extends `Transformer`

```
interface NumberTransformer extends Transformer<number> {
    type: 'number',
    apply<number>(data: number) : number
}

interface StringTransformer extends Transformer<string> {
    type: 'string',
    apply<string>(data: string) : string
}
```

This throws 2 TS errors `(TS6133) 'string'/'number' is declared but its value is never read` and I don't get why

Then, in a Transformer[] list, I want to be able to use the `type` parameter as a type guard like

```
const a : DataTransformer<??>[] = [{
    type: 'number',
    apply: (n :number) => n * 10
},
{
    type: 'string',
    apply: (str :string) => str.substr(0,1)
}];

a.forEach(s => {
  if (s.type === 'string')
    //s.apply is string => string type
});
```

But I don't know what the type of `a` should be ? `DataTransformer<any>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type TransformerKeyType = {
  'number': number,
  'string': string,
}

interface DataTransformer<T extends keyof TransformerKeyType> {
    type: T,
    apply(data: TransformerKeyType[T]) : TransformerKeyType[T]
}

type NumberTransformer = DataTransformer<'number'>;
type StringTransformer = DataTransformer<'string'>;

const a : (DataTransformer<'number'> |  DataTransformer<'string'>)[] = [{
    type: 'number',
    apply: (n) => n * 10
},
{
    type: 'string',
    apply: (str) => str.substr(0,1)
}];

a.forEach(s => {
  if (s.type === 'string') {
    s // here properly we have DataTransformer<'string'>
  }
});
```

Explanation:
`TransformerKeyType` is a type which give us relation between string and type. So we can easly map string `'number'` to type `number`

`DataTransformer` as a generic parameter which takes only keys of `TransformerKeyType` so only `number` or `string`. And automatically body of the type is setting proper `K` by saying that `K` is `TransformerKeyType[T]`. So type for the given property `T` inside `TransformerKeyType`.

`type NumberTransformer = DataTransformer<'number'>;` is instance of our type. It is properly setting apply function with type `number`

`(DataTransformer<'number'> |  DataTransformer<'string'>)[]` is saying that we have an array which contains or DataTransformer with number or DataTransformer with string. It nicely works, in the way that you don't need to declare argument types in apply function, and you can leave `n => n * 10` where type is known as number.